# how to show images in listView with Picasso library from server?

Tags: android

What I'm trying to do is fetch images from database and show them in listView. for this i am using one adapter and list elements class but it is not showing any image but one string value that passed from main activity to elements class actually address of the image in which it is stored in database. Like this

Please don't make it duplicate

http://howdysend.com/Howdy/uploads/6.png ... actually that is the address of the image in database and 6 is the id of the image. Here is my code

Main activity

```
 listEvents.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapterNewsFeed);



        adapterNewsFeed = new AdapterNewsFeed(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_events_list_in_newsfeed);
        listEvents.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapterNewsFeed);


        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");

            int count = 0;
            String EventTitle, EventDate, FriendName,friend_id,image;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                friend_id=JO.getString("friend_id");
                EventTitle = JO.getString("address");
                EventDate = JO.getString("DOB");
                FriendName = JO.getString("name");
                image=("http://howdysend.com/Howdy/uploads/" + friend_id + ".png");

                EventsElements eventsElements = new EventsElements(image,EventTitle, EventDate, FriendName);



                adapterNewsFeed.add(eventsElements);
                listEvents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {

                        EventsElements eventsElements =(EventsElements) adapterNewsFeed.getItem(position);
                        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), SendGreetings.class);

                        i.putExtra("user_id", eventsElements.getFriendName());
                        startActivity(i);


                    }
                });
```

Elements Class

```
public class EventsElements {
private String EventTitle, EventDate,FriendName;
public String image;


public EventsElements(String EventTitle,String EventDate,String FriendName, String image){
    this.setEventTitle(EventTitle);
    this.setEventDate(EventDate);
    this.setFriendName(FriendName);

    this.setImage(image);

}
public String getEventTitle(){
    return EventTitle;
}
public void setEventTitle(String EventTitle) {
    this.EventTitle = EventTitle;
}

public String getEventDate() {
    return EventDate;
}

public void setEventDate(String EventDate) {

    this.EventDate = EventDate;
}

public  String getFriendName() {
    return FriendName;
}

public void setFriendName(String FriendName) {

    this.FriendName = FriendName;
}
public  String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {

    this.image = image;
}


}
```

And AdapterNewsFeed

```
public class AdapterNewsFeed extends ArrayAdapter {
List list=new ArrayList();
public AdapterNewsFeed(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context,resource);

}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public void add(EventsElements object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    view=convertView;
    ElementsHolder elemetsHolder;
    if (view==null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_events_list_in_newsfeed,parent,false);
        elemetsHolder=new ElementsHolder();
        elemetsHolder.EventTitle=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.EventTitle);
        elemetsHolder.EventDate=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.EventDate);
        elemetsHolder.FriendName=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.FriendName);
        elemetsHolder.imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.FriendsUserImage);
        view.setTag(elemetsHolder);
    }
    else
    {
        elemetsHolder=(ElementsHolder) view.getTag();

    }
    EventsElements eventsElements=(EventsElements)this.getItem(position);
    elemetsHolder.EventTitle.setText(eventsElements.getEventTitle());
    elemetsHolder.EventDate.setText(eventsElements.getEventDate());
   elemetsHolder.FriendName.setText(eventsElements.getFriendName());
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(Uri.parse(eventsElements.getImage())).fit().into(elemetsHolder.imageView);

    return view;
}





static class ElementsHolder
{
    TextView EventTitle,EventDate,FriendName;
    ImageView imageView;
    String user_id;
}



 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is from Url so basically you don't need `Uri.parse(eventsElements.getImage()`. Instead just set your url like this

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(eventsElements.getImage()).fit().into(elemetsHolder.imageView);
```

For more info check https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Picasso-Library

Hope this helps!!

Comment: i have also tried this but its not working. showing the same results     @g2o

Comment: please add a `Log.d(TAG,"url"+eventsElements.getImage());` before call Picasso and tell me what is the result..